# How to get <p> of specific div in cheerio?

Tags: jquery

I want to get specific

values of a div. How can I get this ?

HTML code :

```
<form id="frmThis" name="frmThis" method="post" action="">
        <div class="usefull_links" style="width: 184px; margin-right:8px;">
            <div class="links_btm" style="width: 180px;">
                <div class="link_btm2" style="width: 180px;">
                    <h2 align="center" style="padding-top:10px; margin-top: 0px; font-size:14px;">BIN Status</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="links_text" style="width:175px;">
                    <p style="padding-left:10px; font-size:12px;">
                        Do you need to know the present status of a business firm ?
                    </p>
                    <p style="padding-left:10px; margin-bottom:0px; font-size:12px;">
                        Enter BIN
                    </p>
                    <p style="padding-left:10px; margin-top:0px; font-size:12px;">
                        <input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" size="20" autocomplete="off">
                    </p>
                    <p style=" font-size:12px; padding-left:85px;">
                        <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" id="btnSubmit"  value="Search" />
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; color:green; font-weight:bold;" align="center" style="color:#FF0000"> Name: BRAC AARONG<br>Address: MEGHNA TOWER PLOT # 1 BLOCK # G, ZOO ROAD SECTION # 1 MIRPUR,DHAKA.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How can I get value of   Name: BRAC AARONG
Address: MEGHNA TOWER PLOT # 1 BLOCK # G, ZOO ROAD SECTION # 1 MIRPUR,DHAKA.

?? Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery to get the div with class `links_text` and get the last p

```
jQuery('div.links_text').find('p:last')
```

you could get all the p tags and get the last one

```
jQuery('p').last()
```

there are many different ways

With that you would get the jQuery object. If you need the text, just use `.text()` method

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<p>` element an id/class of "data" (or whatever) and use the .text() method...

HTML

```
<p id="data" style="font-size:12px; color:green; font-weight:bold;" align="center" style="color:#FF0000"> Name: BRAC AARONG<br>Address: MEGHNA TOWER PLOT # 1 BLOCK # G, ZOO ROAD SECTION # 1 MIRPUR,DHAKA.</p>
```

JS

```
var text = $('data').text();
```